# Performance issue in react js

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I am currently using reactJS version "15.0.1" in my web application. In one of the feature we need to keep pooling some information continuously after each 2 seconds. So we receive the response which is List of some object(700/1000 items in list) which we update and show in the react web application. The Problem is after some time the application becomes unresponsive and takes too much time for any operation. On profiling I found its render, batch updates and dispatch event in react js that takes the longest time. Is there any recommended way to get away with the performance issue in react. The feature needs to be refreshed every 2 seconds and list size is more than 1000 items each time.

The performance issue is observed in IE and Chrome browser.

Comment: make sure you have a proper key element given to each element so that react knows that it doesn't have to rerender it if its the same list element

Comment: I think it's because of re-rendering of components...if you update the list via props then using the componentWillUpdate() may cause memory leaks...try using logs to identify the scenario regarding continuously rendering of components

Comment: if you got some nested components that SHOULD NOT be re-rendered after polling and updating the state, that is you only need to make shallow compares,  you can try the PureComponent  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code, maybe you have a memory leak? You could try to mark your objects for garbage collection at the end of your methods.

```
listOfSomeObject = null;
```

Here is a good article capturing some methods to identify and fix memory leaks.

https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/